# How should I adress (grammatically) a referee whose gender is unknown?

Tags: peer-review, grammar

I'm responding to an anonymous referee who made comments and suggestions on an article I wrote.

Since I don't know the gender, I thought of two possibilities:

1. We agree with the referee on **its** comment...
2. We agree with the referee on **their** comment...

Is either of these the proper way to refer to the referee? Or should I just write "he/she" "his/her" on every occasion?

Comment: Number 1 is just wrong in English (American for sure, British also in my experience). Number 2 is fine. A further alternative would be 'We agree with comment #2, and have...". If you have to respond to a comment, it really doesn't matter which referee made it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English grammar and usage. Possibly on topic on the [English Language Learners website](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: From the `grammar` tag: *Questions about proper use of grammar specific to academic writing.*

Comment: I can count three questions on Meta regarding gender, made in the last two weeks: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/gendered-pronoun-usage, http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3499/should-an-individual-users-request-for-gender-neutral-language-be-honored, http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/how-do-we-feel-about-gender-specific-terms. I find it hard to understand why the users who closed this question believed it to be non related to Academia.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47049/discussion-on-question-by-gabriel-how-should-i-adress-grammatically-a-referee). Those voting to close please do so, those voting to reopen please do so. Please take all other comments to either chat or [meta].

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The use of [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), as in your second option,

2. We agree with the referee on their comment...

is perfectly appropriate. You can also use some [other alternatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-specific_and_gender-neutral_pronouns#Alternatives_to_generic_he), most notably he/she, as in e.g.

3. We agree with the referee on his/her comment...

I would discourage you from using some of the more niche alternatives, such as [Spivak pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun), in correspondence that's this formal.

On the other hand, your first alternative (We agree with the referee on its comment...) **should not** be used under any circumstances. It is considered extremely rude by native English speakers, since it reduces the referee to the level of an inanimate thing. If you use it you can hope, at best, to come off as someone with a very poor command of the English language.

Comment: Thanks EP. I had my reservations about using *it* as an example, but it was the only alternative to *they* I could think of.

Comment: "Agreeing with the referee on his/her/their comment" is exactly the same as "Agreeing with the referee's comment", which completely avoids the gender issue.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's already addressed in other answers (and please keep in mind [this comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78456/#comment192419_78459) by the OP). Or must every SE answer indicate every possible variant that can be used?

Comment: +1 Thankfully the absurd restriction on singular they put about by grammar mavens has more or less lost its influence and so it is now unlikely that anyone will object to this construct.

Comment: @JackAidley  - - yes, it's much more important to avoid a situation where one is may incorrectly believe you are rudely making assumptions about a person's gender than making people work hard to figure out what exactly you're talking about.

Answer (score 15):

Why not

> We agree with the referee's comment.

(I gathered my answer from the question ["Agree on" vs. "agree with" vs. "agree to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73696/31134) on English SE)

Comment: It looks like I beat Scott by 14 seconds.

Comment: As I mentioned in one of my comments on the original question, I can probably avoid the use of any pronoun *in this particular example*. I am not sure I can avoid using it throughout the entire letter, hence why I need an alternative.

Comment: This is the most correct answer.  One can virtually always write a scholarly paper (or a review of such or a response to the review) without the use of personal pronouns outside of direct quotations.  An author can guide the reader through a convoluted argument or proof without referring to the reader as *"you"* or the author as *"me"* or *"I"* (however, many texts used the personal pronoun *"we"* in such discussions to mean the thinking that the author and the reader are doing together, the prohibition of this usage appears to now be an anachronism).

Comment: @Gabriel, actually in the posited situation, this happens to be the clearest use of language.  I understand your point, but perhaps a less tortuous example would be helpful.

Comment: I agree that *in this particular example* this might be the best solution. As I said though, I am making a more general question, not just about *this particular example*.

Answer (score 5):

In "unknown" gender situations, I use constructions like s/he and his/her.

Answer (score 3):

How about "We agree with the referee's comment."  In general, less words are just better for conveying a message.  If you must pick a genderless pronoun, "he" does not necessarily convey gender, and is perfectly acceptable in most cases.  If you feel you must, the first use you could use s\he, his\her, or the like, to prove that you make no assumptions about the gender of the referee, and then use he or him for the rest, because it just sounds better.

Comment: I will not downvote this answer, since there is nothing wrong with it (and downvotes are to be used for BAD answers, not answers one disagrees with). But I disagree that using "he" is the best option.

Comment: I agree with Tom about the use of "he". I believe it does convey gender, and should not be used as a gender-neutral alternative.

Comment: Similar to this answer: I have recently seen "she" as the gender-neutral pronoun in academic contexts more and more often, especially in math contexts (your field is not mentioned but this is the one I have experience with).

Comment: I'll pile on - "he" is only construed as a gender-neutral pronoun by males. For people that do care about gender neutrality, this shouldn't be used. Downvoting since the only correct part of this post is already available elsewhere without the wrong bits.

Comment: I'll chime in. There is a long history of treating both 'he', 'him', 'man', 'her', and 'she' as gender neutral. Examples are wide. The poem "No Man is an Island" is not saying that women are isolationists. Another example is 'feminists'; they advocate for men's rights too. I've read technical reference books referring to the prospective reader as 'her'.

Comment: @RichardRast, so would "she" be more acceptable than "he"?  Either seems wrong to me.  "They" is horrible.  There may be a move on to promote it as a gender neutral singular, but it's simply confusing.  It's not always contextually clear that you're talking about one person.  If I need to pick a way to err, I'll go with the way more people are likely to understand what I'm trying to say.  As to continued he\she after the first use, its just awkward.  Alternating between he and she just makes it unclear whether you're referring to the same person or different people.

Comment: @E.P. -- to so positively assert that "he" can't be properly used as gender-neutral disagrees with the wikipedia post that you labeled "alternatives" in your own answer.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I wouldn't recommend either (I would use "they" which you dislike). It was purely a comment on the answer, that "she" is also used for a similar purpose. Alternating is definitely confusing.